# mipsel-linux-g++ object not recognized by mipsel-linux-objdump

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, embedded, openwrt

I'm using the OpenWrt [toolchain](http://downloads.openwrt.org/kamikaze/8.09.2/brcm47xx/) to build a C++ application, which makes use of a C library but I doubt that's relevant.

I have two files `file.h` (which contains a C++ class along with the implementation) and `main.cpp` which makes use of that class.

First I tried creating an object from `file.h`

```
 mipsel-linux-g++ -Wall -c -Ipath_to/staging_dir_mipsel/include -Ipath_to/staging_dir_mipsel/usr/incude file.h -o file.o
```

Which gives no error and creates the object file. I do the same thing with `main.cpp` but had issues with linking them together.

When I run

```
mipsel-linux-readelf -h main.o
```

It returns the header of the elf object

When I run

```
mipsel-linux-readelf -h file.o
```

It returns

```
readelf: Error: Unable to read in 0x2d78 bytes of section headers
readelf: Error: Not an ELF file - it has the wrong magic bytes at the start
```

Any pointers? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> gcc ...  -c file.h -o file.o

It is *exceedingly* unusual to put C code into a header file, and attempt to compile it in above manner into object code.

In fact, it is so unusual, that GCC, given above command, doesn't do it. Instead, it compiles `file.h` into a *precompiled header* (normally called `.gch`, but forced to be called `.o` by your unfortunate `-o` option).

Therefore, it's not at all surprising that `file.o` is not an `ELF` file. Just run `file file.o` and see if it prints `GCC precompiled header (version 013) for C` or some such.

If you really intend `file.h` to be compilable to an ELF object `file.o`, name it `file.c` instead.

Comment: It wasn't C code, it was C++ code as it was a C++ header, and from what I've seen it's not uncommon to implement class methods in header files. I wouldn't have considered compiling C header files. Nevertheless you were right.